# tinyMCE add image

Tags: image, tinymce, addition

I have problem with tinyMCE. If I add image from external url (http://www.somesite.com/image.jpg) all works perfect and and the image will show in my text. But if I add an image from a folder on server, the image will not show because I use htaccess to rewrite the url.

Web domain:  `www.web.domain.com`
If I insert image from `www.web.domain.com/images/img.jpg` and show this text on the page `www.web.domain.com/en/Category-1/`, the image doesn't show because tinyMCE adds `img src` as "./images/img.jpg"

Any idea if it is possible to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to TinyMCE using relative URLs by default. Check out the [FAQ entry](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F) on the TinyMCE site for the various settings that might help.